# Posting to multiple friends walls after the Feb 6th change

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

As of Feb 6th Facebook no longer allows us to post to someone's wall using the graph API.

Their suggested fix is to use the feed dialog to post to a friend's wall using the "to:" parameter. As far as a I can tell, the "to:" parameter can only be a single user.

Is there anyway using javascript or PHP apis (or any other way) to allow the user to post to multiple users' walls (either selected inside the dialog or from a list of ids I get from somewhere else) ?

Comment: Honestly this is not at all a duplicate of that question.  My question is specifically about how to post to multiple friends' walls with a single dialog post.  If you were to fully read my question and fully read the question that is linked as a duplicate that you will see they are very different.  I mention the answer to the previous question in my question and say that using a feed dialog with the "to:" parameter seems to not work at all to post to multiple Facebook users at the same time.  It really seems that the questions was flagged erroneously, please remove your flag!

Comment: Now someone downvoted the question, can you please at least explain why this question should be downvoted.  Or why my assertion about it not being a duplicate is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Fine question and this is actually something that I've been in contact with Facebook about.

The short answer is no, there is no clear and succinct way to post to multiple walls at once anymore.

The longer answer....

Word from Facebook is that they removed the option to post to multiple walls because of the sheer amount of spam that went out through the open graph API.  To save everyone's sanity they decided to remove the functionality entirely.  Not necessarily an ideal scenario for those of us who try to use it legitimately, but I suppose you pick your battles when you have 1 billion users.

The short version of their answer was that their are two options:

1. (as you mentioned) you can select a series of friends and use the to: parameter in the feed dialog to send them one at a time.  This makes it diffic
2. If possible figure out which users are already a user on your Facebook app and send an email to their @facebook.com email address.  IF they have already authenticated your app, the notification jewel will light up for them and it will appear as unread in their inbox.  If they have NOT authenticated your app, it will go to the user's "other" mailbox which does not light up the jewel.  Not quite the same thing as the feed dialog because it doesn't actually post to their wall, but hypothetically still gets their attention.

Those are the only options left for those of us with web apps.